# Python, Pandas Data frame syntax

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame(df) and I am trying to copy first line from df to df1 by the following syntax.

```
df1=df.iloc[0].copy()
```

and when I printed df1 the data frame look like this

```
device_consumption_key                2700848
eagle_id                         d8d5b9008b92
device_id                    002446000006983b
component_id                               0b
read_dt                   2017-10-25 20:05:24
msg_dt                    2017-09-15 14:09:19
delivered                                0.86
received                                    0
unit                                      kWh
creation_time             2017-10-25 20:06:00
etl_pid                        20171102184518
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

if I used a different syntax liek below the frame looks like a da-->

```
df1=df.iloc[[0]].copy()
```

[Can't able to show the full picture but I guess you got the idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m8fc.png)

Why is that?

Comment: When you slice `[0]` you get a Series, when you slice `[[0]]` you get a df

Answer (score 0):

The two difference slicing methods, using double brackets and single brackets return a `DataFrame` and a `Series` respectively:

```
>>> type(df.iloc[[0]].copy())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>>> type(df.iloc[0].copy())
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

`Series` are by default displayed with the column names as the index, and the values as *what looks like a column*, but should not be considered as such.

**More details**:

A `Series`, based on the [`pandas` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.html) is a

> One-dimensional ndarray with axis labels (including time series).

Whereas a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)

> Can be thought of as a dict-like container for Series objects

Comment: It's not always quite that simple, for example, with this dataframe: `df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(range(5)), index=[1, 2, 3, 3, 3])`, `df.loc[3]` returns a DataFrame, while `df.loc[1]` returns a Series.  You can always pass a list to get a dataframe, but not passing a list does not guarantee a series.

Comment: @user3483203 Good argument not to have duplicated indexes !

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [.loc documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc) , specifically (highlights added by me)

> Single label. **Note this returns the row as a Series.**
>
> `df.loc['viper']`

And

> List of labels. **Note using [[]] returns a DataFrame.**
>
> `df.loc[['viper', 'sidewinder']]`

Basically when you slice using a single label, such as `df.iloc[0]`, you get a `pd.Series` object. When you slice using a *list of labels*, such as `[[0]]`, you get a `pd.DataFrame`.

*The same logic applies to `.iloc`*

---

As highlighted in comments, this is assuming *unique indexes*. If you use `loc` in a data frame that has duplicated indexes, then unexpected results might arise (which is one strong argument for you *not to* use duplicated indexes !)